# How to map a sphere of influence in R

Tags: r, google-maps, dictionary

I don't have any code yet because I am trying to figure out where to begin.

I am using map('state, 'texas) to draw Texas and am geoplotting universities on it.  I want R to figure out the sphere of influence that university has with in the state and map it out.

Eventually I will geoplot high schools on the map as well and I would like for R to see who's sphere of influence that high school is in.

Does anyone know what package to begin with?

Comment: How do you define "sphere of influence"?

Comment: I think of it as making a boundry where each point on the boundry is halfway between the current point and the next closest point.

Comment: @user2884824 The for any point on the map it is in the 'sphere of influence' of the closest university by basic euclidean distance

Comment: @user2884824 that sounds like a voronoi diagram.

Answer (score 2):

Your description matches with the concept of a [voronoi diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram). It partitions an area into polygons based on the locations of points (e.g. your high schools). All the points in the polygon are closer to that particular high school than to all other high schools.

An example using `ggplot2`, copied from [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2-dev/NrqKn2mR2VQ):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(deldir)
library(scales)
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)

# make fake points
n <- 50
k <- 4
mat <- cbind(rnorm(n), rnorm(n))
df <- as.data.frame(mat)
names(df) <- c('x','y')

# triangulate
xrng <- expand_range(range(df$x), .05)
yrng <- expand_range(range(df$y), .05)
deldir <- deldir(df, rw = c(xrng, yrng))

# voronoi
qplot(x, y, data = df)  +
  geom_segment(
    aes(x = x1, y = y1, xend = x2, yend = y2), size = .25,
    data = deldir$dirsgs, linetype = 2
  ) + 
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

[image]